# FaceBook Additional Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have came across this facebook page.

https://www.facebook.com/hadalabosg

The page have an additional page named, Free Lotion / Free Sample apart from the usual Photos, Likes, Notes and Videos page. When I go into the **Free Sample** page, the page requires me to '*Like*' the page in order to key in my details. I went on to '*Like*' the page and the page refresh. When it refreshed, FaceBook prompts me to Allow Access to an app or give permission to post feeds on my behalf which is similar to an app.

May I know, how do I create an additional page for my page and do something similar like that one above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Thanks CBroe! I will start from that link.

Comment: I have managed to add a page tab to my page but I happened to realize that there are some page tab that does require app authorization while some do not. May I know what is the difference and how to achieve either both? Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/

Comment: I don't quite understand on what it says inside the page. I still couldn't get the app authorization popup dialog showing up.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/